# Uncaught (in promise) with func().then().catch() | pass error message to outer promise function | nested promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I'm trying to execute this function varlinkCall and add a callback function in .then(), and deal with err with varlinkCall in .catch().

```
varlinkCall(utils.PODMAN, "io.projectatomic.podman.RemoveImage", JSON.parse('{"name":"' + image.Id + '"}'))
                .then((reply) => {
                    console.log(reply.image);
                })
                .catch(ex => {
                    console.log(ex);
                })
```

varlinkCall() called varlinkCallChannel(), I add .catch() at the end of varlinkCallChannel(), but I can't get the error message in varlinkCall() function, it was cought by varlinkCallChannel(). How can I get the error message ?

```
function varlinkCallChannel(channel, method, parameters) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    function on_close(event, options) {
        reject(options.problem || options);
    }

    function on_message(event, data) {
        channel.removeEventListener("message", on_message);
        channel.removeEventListener("close", on_close);

        // FIXME: support answer in multiple chunks until null byte
        if (data[data.length - 1] != 0) {
        reject("protocol error: expecting terminating 0");
        return;
        }

        var reply = decoder.decode(data.slice(0, -1));
        var json = JSON.parse(reply);
        if (json.error)
        reject(json.error)
        else if (json.parameters) {
        // debugging
        // console.log("varlinkCall", method, "→", JSON.stringify(json.parameters));
        resolve(json.parameters)
        } else
        reject("protocol error: reply has neither parameters nor error: " + reply);
    }

    channel.addEventListener("close", on_close);
    channel.addEventListener("message", on_message);
    channel.send(encoder.encode(JSON.stringify({ method, parameters: (parameters || {}) })));
    channel.send([0]); // message separator
    })
    .catch(err=>{console.log(err)});
}

/**
 * Do a varlink call on a new channel. This is more expensive than
 * `varlinkCallChannel()` but allows multiple parallel calls.
 */
export function varlinkCall(channelOptions, method, parameters) {
    var channel = cockpit.channel(Object.assign({payload: "stream", binary: true, superuser: "require" }, channelOptions));
    var response = varlinkCallChannel(channel, method, parameters);
    response.finally(() => channel.close());
    return response;
}
```

If I delete the catch at the end of varlinkCallChannel(), I will get 'Uncaught (in promise)'.

Comment: Where you catch in order to log, remember to rethrow the error.
Also, always reject with an `Error` (or `TypeError`, `RangeError` etc).

Comment: thx, can you give a specific implementation of that, rethrow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should delete the `catch` in `varlinkCallChannel`.

Your problem is in `varlinkCall`:

```
export function varlinkCall(channelOptions, method, parameters) {
    var channel = cockpit.channel(Object.assign({payload: "stream", binary: true, superuser: "require" }, channelOptions));
    var promise1 = varlinkCallChannel(channel, method, parameters);
    var promise2 = promise1.finally(() => channel.close());
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return promise1;
}
```

Here you are creating a second promise that will get rejected just like the `promise1` that you return, and this rejection of `promise2` is not getting handled anywhere. You'll want to return the chained promise:

```
export function varlinkCall(channelOptions, method, parameters) {
    var channel = cockpit.channel(Object.assign({payload: "stream", binary: true, superuser: "require" }, channelOptions));
    return varlinkCallChannel(channel, method, parameters).finally(() => {
        channel.close()
    });
}
```

Comment: really helpful. Thanks. :)